# Operator * and + produces wrong result in digital mars

Tags: c

I am trying to calculate a number which produce Longest Collatz sequence. But here is a strange problem. `3n+1` become `38654705674` when `n` is 3. I do not see an error. here is the full code:

```c
/* 6.c -- calculates Longest Collatz sequence */
#include <stdio.h>
long long get_collatz_length(long long);
int main(void)
{
    long long i;
    long long current, current_count, count;

    current_count = 1;
    current = 1;
    for(i=2;i<1000000;i++)
    {
        // works fine when i is 2 the next line take eternity when i is 3;
        count = get_collatz_length(i);
        if(current_count <= count)
        {
            current = i;
            current_count = count;
        }
    }
    printf("%lld %lld\n", current, current_count);

    return 0;
}

long long get_collatz_length(long long num)
{
    long long count;

    count = 1;
    while(num != 1)
    {
        printf("%lld\n", num);
        if(num%2)
        {
            num = num*3+1;        // here it is;
        }
        else
        {
            num/=2;
        }
        count++;
    }
    puts("");
    return count;
}
```

Comment: this won't compile because of this line `count = get_collatz_length(i);3`. And `printf("%lld %lld/n", current, current_count);` won't print out a new line

Comment: Ah!, it was a part of the comment in the previous line. I just moved it in a single line because of the vertical scroll bar. It is not part of the code. thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: What is `sizeof(long long)` on your platform?

Comment: Seems fine on [ideone](http://ideone.com/HGSpbG).

Comment: `printf("%zd", sizeof(long long));` reply's 8. @slugonamission

Comment: Does it fail as well with simplified code (see @RetiredNinja's comment)?

Comment: you're not using the return value of `get_collatz_length` so why don't just use void?

Comment: I just checked it. It fails too. `:(`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc No sir, I am using it. See the main function

Comment: What is the output from your compiled version?  The non-simplified version works too up to 10.  http://ideone.com/5iO44q  You should try with just an int rather than a long long.

Comment: Sorry I've just looked at ideone

Comment: @RetiredNinja A few line: It do not stop. No segment fault either. http://pastebin.com/Xdk8fniZ

Comment: @RetiredNinja That was  from your simplified version.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with `long long`.  I changed all of the cases to just long and the printf spec to %d and it works with digital mars.  *shrug*

Comment: This code works fine here too

Comment: Ok, maybe a digital mars issue. Waiting if anybody else can give an explanation.

Comment: Writing a good optimizing compiler can be a daunting task. It involves a lot of transformation steps that are ridiculously difficult to debug. Many real world tests are needed, see what happened with Linux and GCC 4.9 or the periodic bugs caught by GMP. In this sense, `dmc` appears to be much  underpowered wrt its alternatives, like `gcc`, `clang` and `icc`. My 2 cents: leave `dmc` and stick with one which is in use out there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's seems to be bug in `dmc` compiler, that fails to handle `long long` type correctly. Here is narrowed test-case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long long num = 3LL;

    /*printf("%lld\n", num);*/

    num = num * 3LL;

    char *t = (char *) &num;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        printf("%x\t", t[i]);
    putchar('\n');

    /*printf("%lld\n", num);*/

    return 0;
}
```

It produces (little endian, so `0x900000009` == `38 654 705 673`):

```
9       0       0       0       9       0       0       0
```

From dissasembly it looks that it stores 64-bit integer as two 32-bit registers:

```
.data:0x000000be    6bd203  imul edx,edx,0x3
.data:0x000000c1    6bc803  imul ecx,eax,0x3
.data:0x000000c4    03ca    add ecx,edx
.data:0x000000c6    ba03000000  mov edx,0x3
.data:0x000000cb    f7e2    mul edx
.data:0x000000cd    03d1    add edx,ecx
.data:0x000000cf    31c0    xor eax,eax
```

---

I additionaly tested it with [`objconv`](http://www.agner.org/optimize/objconv.zip) tool, that just confirms my initial diagnose:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mul(void)
{
    long long a;
    long long c;

    a = 5LL;
    c = a * 3LL;

    printf("%llx\n", c);
}

int main(void)
{
    mul();

    return 0;
}
```

disassembly (single section):

```
>objconv.exe -fmasm ..\dm\bin\check.obj

_mul    PROC NEAR
        mov     eax, 5                                  ; 0000 _ B8, 00000005
        cdq                                             ; 0005 _ 99
        imul    edx, edx, 3                             ; 0006 _ 6B. D2, 03
        imul    ecx, eax, 3                             ; 0009 _ 6B. C8, 03
        add     ecx, edx                                ; 000C _ 03. CA
        mov     edx, 3                                  ; 000E _ BA, 00000003
        mul     edx                                     ; 0013 _ F7. E2
        add     edx, ecx                                ; 0015 _ 03. D1
        push    edx                                     ; 0017 _ 52
        push    eax                                     ; 0018 _ 50
        push    offset FLAT:?_001                       ; 0019 _ 68, 00000000(segrel)
        call    _printf                                 ; 001E _ E8, 00000000(rel)
        add     esp, 12                                 ; 0023 _ 83. C4, 0C
        ret                                             ; 0026 _ C3
_mul    ENDP
```

Note that `mul edx` operates implicitely on `eax`. The result is stored in both registers, higher part (in this case `0`) in stored in `edx`, while lower in `eax`.

Comment: Wow, this looks pretty serious :(

Comment: Very well then. I will choose an alternative. Is `char *t = (char *) &num;` garanteed to work?

Comment: @silentboy: Yup, but it was little paranoid, `printf("%llx\n", num);` shows correct hex value as well.

Comment: It's very strange to have such a bug on basic types' operations nowadays. However I don't know why the OP uses this because I've never heard this compiler before